# Possible houses in Oblivion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I've been playing The Elder Scrolls games for many years and I have recently re-installed Oblivion after a break of more than a year. I'm using my savegame from that time and now I have problems finding my old stuff. Let me explain that.

In my list of bought houses there is a 0. So I haven't bought any houses in the towns of Cyrodiil. But I remember that I had a house where I put my stuff in, such as alchemy tools, weapons and armor. From time to time you are given empty houses of lost (or killed) NPCs. From a certain point on you can use this house as your own because the items inside can't be stolen anymore but legally taken which indicates that it is kinda "your house" now. My problem is that I can't remember where I could have left my stuff one year ago.

Can anyone give me some examples of possible houses where I could have left my stuff? I remember for example Glarthir's House but I already looked there and found nothing. :/

I completed the campaign, Thieves Guild, Mages Guild, Dark Brotherhood, Shivering Isles, Knights of the Nine and some other stuff...

TIA. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The unofficial Elder Scrolls wiki has a good database of the traditional houses (like those that can be purchased in each of the major cities) *as well as* a list of the houses that don't count for your "houses owned" statistic. The wiki also has a complete list of non-respawning containers; normally, the contents of each crate, chest, and container gets reset and randomized every 3 in-game days.

Here is the page for [houses](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Houses);

Here is the page for non-respawning [containers](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Containers#Safe_Containers)

If you can't find your stuff stored in either the "free" houses, or the safe containers, you may simply be out of luck, pending a burst of sudden remembrance.

Comment: Excellent list, thank you. :) I found my stuff in White Stallion Lodge. Without that list it would have taken days (rl) to find my stuff... :)